# DIY Photobooth: LED puck lights potentiometer suggestions

Tags: led, raspberry-pi, potentiometer, gpio, digital-potentiometer

I'm building a Raspberry Pi powered photobooth, and want to add some lighting.

I purchased this set of [led puck lights](http://www.goodearthlighting.com/media/pdf/SPEC_AC1012-WHG-03LF3.pdf), and would love to control their intensity from the Raspberry Pi, instead of the knob on the driver. The first row in [this spec sheet](http://www.shineretrofits.com/downloads/dl/file/id/442/ktld_constant_current_series.pdf) describes the LED driver.

My goal is to replace the knob/potentiometer with a digital one and control through SPI, but I'm at the edge of my EE skills and not sure what the best digipot is for my application.

1. Any suggestions for a digipot?
2. Am I approaching this the best way?

Comment: I don't have much experience with the Pi. Do you know what PWM is, and is it possible here? Might be simpler than a digipot.

Comment: @Gregd'Eon I'm beginning to get more familiar with it. Still not sure how to go about implementing it with the off the shelf hardware... There's just less known about it if you don't build it yourself, as pointed out by andy-aka below. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to determine several things about the circuit around the pot to be able to say with confidence that a digipot is suitable.

For instance, the maximum peak voltages with respect to 0 volts on all terminals. This means peak dc as well as peak ac voltages.

Once this is defined you can begin to choose a digipot but, this is not straightforward. It might be that the current pot controls several tens of milli amps of current. This needs to be determined else the digipot you might choose will internally burn on overcurrent.

Another problem might be that both ends of the current pot are sat at several volts above 0 volts. This means that your serial control data voltages are inconveniently not ground referenced. In cases like this you might need to generate an isolated voltage supply AND an isolated digital control. This can get messy because an isolated supply might create common mode noise that causes odd things to happen like random LED flickering.

You might get lucky of course but without a decent analysis of how the current pot circuit works it's hard to say.